# jQuery to loop through an animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a helicopter panning across the screen on [this site](http://www.koodoocreative.co.uk/~stagesca) it currently goes from left to right. But after 30 seconds, I'd like it to change direction. Then after 30 seconds change direction again. A loop round really in that it goes

- left > right
- right > left

In a loop.

I am using [jQuery Spritely](http://spritely.net/) to animate the helicopter.

My current jQuery is setup as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{       
/* Initial Helicopter Movement */
 $('#helicopter').pan({fps: 30, speed: 1.5, depth: 10, dir: 'right'});
 $('#helicopter').spState(1);

 setInterval(function() {
   $("#helicopter").spStop();
   $('#helicopter').pan({fps: 30, speed: 1.5, dir: 'left'});
   $('#helicopter').spState(2);
   $("#helicopter").spStart();
 }, 5000 ); 
};
```

How would I go about achieving my loop?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have never used `jQuery Spritely`, but I am confusing that your function in `setInterval`. Obviously, your helicopter direction is `right` at first, and 5000ms later your `setInterval` make it to `left`. Another 5000ms later, it still change the direction to `left`. So I think you should change direction every times in the function in `setInterval`. Hope it might be of some help to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code block inside the setInterval function to this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    if (props.dir == 'left') {
    props.dir = 'right';
    $("#helicopter").spState(1).spChangeDir('right');
}
    else { 
        props.dir = 'left';
    $("#helicopter").spState(2).spChangeDir('left');
    }
}, 5000 );
```

Here you're just checking the `props.dir` value after every 5 seconds and alternating the direction. `Spritely JS` has an in-built `spChangeDir()` method and does not need the properties to be set and reset after every interval.

Comment: You'll need to update your helicopter graphic by removing the whitespace between the two images, if you want the helicopter to turn back and move on the same line. It's position is currently shifting down a few pixels when you're changing the state.

Comment: Thats perfect @kayen. Thanks very much. Paried with gilesc's answer I've finally achieved what I want. Next is looking at that whitespace issue to prevent it from being knocked down.

Answer (score 1):

Have a variable track which direction you are currently going and change it in your interval every time the function is triggered.

```
$(function() {

 var dir = 'right';

 /* Initial Helicopter Movement */
 $('#helicopter').pan({fps: 30, speed: 1.5, depth: 10, dir: dir});
 $('#helicopter').spState(1);

 setInterval(function() {

   if (dir == 'left') dir = 'right';
   else dir = 'left';

   $("#helicopter").spStop();
   $('#helicopter').pan({fps: 30, speed: 1.5, dir: dir});
   $('#helicopter').spState(2);
   $("#helicopter").spStart();
 }, 30000 ); 
});
```

But you could optimize your code a bit as fps and speed is always the same

```
var props = {
  fps:30,
  speed:1.5,
  depth:10,
  dir:'right'
};


$(function() {

 /* Initial Helicopter Movement */
 $('#helicopter').pan(props);
 $('#helicopter').spState(1);

 setInterval(function() {

   if (props.dir == 'left') props.dir = 'right';
   else props.dir = 'left';

   $("#helicopter").spStop();
   $('#helicopter').pan(props);
   $('#helicopter').spState(2);
   $("#helicopter").spStart();
 }, 30000 ); 
});
```

Comment: Hi @gilesc if you have a look at the site now. I have optimized my code as per your answer, But as you can see the Helicopter seems to struggle with the animation and also falls in the wrong direction, Any ideas..?